# Redirection on Custom page

Tags: redirect, login

1. I have created login page template and created the login page through wp-admin->pages. here I select the template 'login'
2. Now I need to redirect user on this page if somebody haven't logged in. wp-admin login and this login page are separate. there is no relation if someone logged in wp-admin or not.
3. The code which I am using as follows, FireFox redirect me to error page saying "The page isn't redirecting properly".

   ```
   if (  !is_admin() ) {

   if(!isset($_COOKIE['login_token']) || $_COOKIE['login_token']=='') {
   //echo $_COOKIE['login_token']."KKKKKKKRRRRRRRR";
   $login_page  = home_url('/login/');

   // Two things happen here, we make sure we are on the login page
   // and we also make sure that the request isn't coming from a form
   // this ensures that our scripts & users can still log in and out.
   //if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    // And away they go...
    wp_redirect($login_page);
   exit();

   }   
   $username=$_POST['log']; 
   $password=$_POST['pwd'];
   echo $_COOKIE['login_token'];
   // try to log into the external service or database with username and password
   //$ext_auth = try2AuthenticateExternalService($username,$password);
   //echo "<pre>"; print_r($ext_auth); echo '</pre>'; 
   // if external authentication was successful
   $ext_auth[0] = 'success';
   if($ext_auth[0]=='success') {

        // find a way to get the user id
        $uname = explode('@',$username);
        $user_id = username_exists($uname[0]); 
        // userdata will contain all information about the user
        //$userdata = get_userdata($user_id);
        //$user = wp_set_current_user($user_id,$username);

        // this will actually make the user authenticated as soon as the cookie is in the browser
       //wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
       $path = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_PATH);
       $host = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
       //$expiry = strtotime('+1 month');
       $expiry = time() + (60 * 1);
       setcookie('login_token', $ext_auth[0], $expiry, $path, $host);
        // the wp_login action is used by a lot of plugins, just decide if you need it
       do_action('wp_login',$userdata->ID);
       //determine WordPress user account to impersonate

       // you can redirect the authenticated user to the "logged-in-page", define('MY_PROFILE_PAGE',1); f.e. first
       //header("Location:http://executiveboard/audit-blog");
       return 'success';

       }
     }


   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user is not logged in, your code will redirect to the login page even if the user is already in the login page so you end up with a infinite redirection loop.

You should check if the user is logged in and the page where he/she is and redirect if he/she is not logged in and if he/she is not in the login page. Add this code to functions.php:

```
 <?php
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_redirect_to_login_page' );
 function wpse_redirect_to_login_page() {
      //You can use also is_page() function to check for specific page instead for a page template
      if( !is_page_template("login-template.php") && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
          wp_redirect( get_permalink( ID_of_login_page ); );
          exit();
      }
 }
 ?>
```

Also, you should take the login/auth process out of the template file. Ore, better just use the `wp_login_form` in your template file. See [How to Make a Custom Login Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Make_a_Custom_Login_Page).